# Potential broken storage in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, crash, 19.04, storage

### Problem

As I described in my previous [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138246/ubuntu-16-04-suddenly-stops-responding-and-behaves-in-a-weird-way) on this site, my dual-booted laptop (with coexisting Windows 10) crashes frequently in Ubuntu system, showing sudden inability to respond to any command, including `sudo shutdown now`.

The problem seems to be more serious than I expected since the following messages prompted when I **have to** shutdown the machine by cutting its power. However, these information is not quite comprehensible to me except that I know it is related to my storage.

This issue really drives me crazy since my work is interrupted from time to time.

Could someone help me, any input is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The file system is corrupt and needs error correction -or- the drive is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, have you installed a driver that allows you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? If so, that's what's corrupting Ubuntu. Uninstall it asap.

Your file system is corrupt. See if this manual `fsck` can fix it...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- **Note**: while you're booted to a Ubuntu Live, start the `Disks` app and check your SMART data.
- type `reboot`